# how do I change the alpha channel along a path in cairo?

Tags: gtk3, alpha, glib, cairo, stroke

In an application using gtk3, I use `cairo` to do some drawing. What I would like to do is increase the transparency along the path. The path can have any shape.

In very simplified terms, I have something like this:

```
#include <cairo.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cairo_surface_t *surface =
        cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 200, 200);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, .1, .1, .1);
    cairo_paint(cr);

    cairo_set_line_cap(cr, CAIRO_LINE_CAP_ROUND);
    cairo_set_line_join(cr, CAIRO_LINE_JOIN_ROUND);
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, 20.0);

    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.6);
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;

    cairo_move_to(cr, x, y);
    x += 150;
    cairo_line_to(cr, x, y);
    cairo_stroke(cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.4);
    cairo_line_to(cr, x, y);
    x -= 50;
    y += 150;
    cairo_line_to(cr, x, y);
    cairo_stroke(cr);

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "mwe.png");
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
    return 0;
}
```

When I draw the sections in pieces, each with a different alpha value, start and end overlap and -- not surprisingly -- I get this result:

[image]

Now my question is whether there is a way to "fade" the line along the path.

I thought of using a mask to restrict the drawing to where the last segment wasn't already (`cairo_clip`?), but don't know how to do that with a non-closed line.

But maybe there is an easier way to achieve this altogether ?

Comment: My best idea is to use a linear pattern with start / stop at the end of your paths and have the alpha increase along that. For your example path, this might look close to what you are asking for (I can provide example C code, if you want), but I don't think it counts as an answer since you say `the path can have any shape`. So... if you want something that also works a for a spiral, then I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: In the example, the path is at an angle. How would a linear pattern solve that? Or would you have it go from start to end point?

Comment: I meant a path just from the very first to the very last point. That's why I don't think this counts as an answer since you likely want this transparency to "follow the path".